# Current measurements for a DC motor being rectified when in reverse direction (differential low pass filter implementation)

Tags: amplifier, pwm, current-measurement, voltage-measurement, low-pass

Recently for a project I've been trying to capture voltage and current characteristics for a DC motor.

To measure current, I'm using a single resistor (R1) in series with the motor, and feeding the voltage signals on either terminal into a TI AMC1302 amplifier.

From the amplifier, I have the differential signals going into a DAQ (sampling at 20 Hz), which computes the difference and calculates current using Ohm's Law. The motor is driven by a 0-5 V PWM signal.

I experienced quite a bit of noise in my measurements with this base setup, and so decided to add a differential low-pass filter on the output of the amplifier with a cutoff frequency of approximately 10 Hz, before the signal enters the DAQ inputs. This helped immensely with the noise, but I'm experiencing odd behavior when the motor is in the reverse direction.

I've included a graph of my current values over time collected from an automated test that ramps the motor to max forward speed and then back down to max reverse speed sinusoidally (done through software).

In the reverse direction, the current transitions to negative values as expected, but then the signal almost appears to be rectified after about -5 A.

I'm a little stuck on trying to figure out what could be causing this issue. I've tried changing the RC configuration but still get the same results. The issue is definitely with the filter, since without the filter the current measurements go fully negative at full reverse speed, albeit with considerable noise.

Any ideas on where this problem could be stemming from would be appreciated, as I'm fairly new to designing filters.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGxcsm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: What about the power supply to the AMC1302 (with respect to the shunt)?  Are you exceeding common-mode limits?

Comment: Correct me if I'm misunderstanding the question, but currently I'm just using the low side for power, so VDD2 and GND2, and that's being supplied by my DAQ so I don't think any limits are being exceeded.

Comment: Please show the complete circuit including motor bridge and AMC1302 power supplies.

Comment: @atsa Please show the full circuit.  If I understand your description, reverse current will pull the "In+" terminal of the AMC1302 below its negative supply rail.

Comment: Just edited the circuit, please let me know if I need to add more detail. I think I understand what you're saying, I'm just a little confused on why the filter itself would be causing this issue since its connected on the output side of the AMC.

Comment: _"currently I'm just using the low side for power,"_ - the high side also needs to be powered with a voltage between 3 V and 5.5 V (datasheet section 6.3 Recommended Operating Conditions VDD1 to GND1). I'm surprised you get anything without it.

Comment: I think the high side is also powered from VDD2 through an isolated transformer, at least according to the actual AMC1302EVM chip datasheet. And I believe GND1 is connected internally to INN. Trying a separate power supply for that side might be worth a shot though.